# Touch ID through Safari

Tags: iphone, mobile, safari, ios8, touch-id

I am working in the mobile version of a website and wonder if we can use touch ID (fingerprint) to login. I heard there is an API in iOS 8 sdk, but is it possible to use it through Safari at least?

Cheers,

Comment: No, you can't at this moment.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, what about 1Password extension for Safari?

Comment: it requires the 1Password App (launch the 1Password App & verify the Touch ID).